# Js Chat Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Javascript(the pure javascript), I'm tryiong to create a chat controller app that does the below.

1. User enters content.
2. There is a post call done to my Knowledge Base.
3. The server responds the message.

Currently, I'm unable to get this post block executed though I click the button.

Below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--[if IE]>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <![endif]-->
<title>Bootstrap Chat Box Example</title>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE STYLE CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- FONT AWESOME  CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- CUSTOM STYLE CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // jQuery Document

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $("#submitmsg").click();
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submitmsg').bind('click', function() {
            var message = $('#usermsg').val();
            $('#chatbox').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
            $('#usermsg').val('');
            //alert(message);

        });
    });

    function serverResponse(message) {
        $('#chatbox').append('<p>Server: ' + message + '</p>');
    }

    $("#submitmsg")
            .click(
                    function() {
                        alert("Hi");
                        var inputtedText = $("#usermsg").val();
                        var params = {};

                        var controllerUrl = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v1.0/knowledgebases/bde3c190-58bd-40d8-9ff1-c35eb18588be/generateAnswer';
                        $.ajax({
                            url : controllerUrl,
                            type : 'POST',
                            data : {
                                "question" : inputtedText
                            },
                            beforeSend : function(xhrObj) {
                                // Request headers
                                xhrObj.setRequestHeader(
                                        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "MyKey");
                                xhrObj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
                                        'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

                            },
                            success : function(data) {
                                var dataObj = data;
                                alert('Data:' + JSON.stringify(dataObj));
                                $('#resultvalue').html(data);
                                serverResponse(JSON.stringify(dataObj));
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
</script>


</head>
<body>

    <nav class="menu">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="back">
                    <img src="acn.jpg" draggable="false" />
                </div>
                <div class="name">Accenture Compliance</div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                        User Name</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
                        Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row pad-top pad-bottom">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="chat-box-new-div">
                    <div class="chat-box-new-head">Compliance Avatar</div>
                    <div class="panel-body chat-box-new">

                        <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                        <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="chat-box-div">
                    <div class="chat-box-head">
                        CHAT HISTORY
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="fa fa-cogs"></span> <span class="sr-only">Toggle
                                    Dropdown</span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body chat-box-main">
                        <div class="chat-box-left">Hello, Welcome!. You can ask me
                            questions on Compliance Policy ..</div>
                        <div class="chat-box-name-left">
                            <img src="compiler-bot-static.gif"
                                alt="bootstrap Chat box user image" class="img-circle" /> - Bot
                        </div>
                        <hr class="hr-clas" />
                        <div class="chat-box-right" id="chatbox"></div>
                        <div class="chat-box-name-right">
                            <img src="smiley.jpg" alt="bootstrap Chat box user image"
                                class="img-circle" /> - You
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-box-footer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter Text Here..." id="usermsg"> <span
                                class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="submitmsg">SEND</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="chat-box-new-div">
                    <div class="chat-box-new-head">Frequently Asked Questions ..
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body chat-box-new">
                        <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                        <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                        <br /> <br /> <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- USING SCRIPTS BELOW TO REDUCE THE LOAD TIME -->
        <!-- CORE JQUERY SCRIPTS FILE -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <!-- CORE BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  FILE -->
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

To check if the function is actually called or not, I've added an alert inside of `("#submitmsg").click(function() {...`, to my surprise, it is not alerting anything, that means that this is not getting called.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? I'd guess that you're being blocked by the SOP given that you're making a cross-domain call

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I didn't have any errors in my console. `Connecting to PORT_NAME_SYMANTEC_PKI_CLIENT_CONTENT_TO_BACKGROUND...
bridge.js:1 Connected: Port
bridge.js:1 Done.
chrome-extension://ahgdclgdhfeingghldkedleghekbfhef/content/detection.js:1 +content/detection.js
chrome-extension://ahgdclgdhfeingghldkedleghekbfhef/content/detection.js:1 -content/detection.js` is my console output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by timing that add click event listener.

Before document trigger ready event, DOM element is loaded not yet.

For this reason js(jquery selector) can not find "submitmsg" element for adding event listener

Check following link & code

https://jsfiddle.net/f6fv1xvw/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // maybe alerted [length = 0] because dom element loaded not yet
    alert("before ready : " + $("#submitmsg").length);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // maybe alerted [length = 1] because dom element loaded completly
        alert("after ready : " + $("#submitmsg").length);

        // need to add event listener this timing(after ready)
        $("#submitmsg").click(function() {
        alert("Hi");
    });
  });
</script>
```

And then check again your source why load jquery 3 times.

```
// called 1 time in head
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

// called 2 time before body
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

// called 3 time in body    
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```